# Cat scratching her ear, can I help?

Tags: cats, scratching

My cat scratches her ears from time to time and sometimes she does it quite hard. I have looked at her ear and it is a little scabby and crusty, and when I rub it she doesn't seem to mind. I have cleaned out her ear with a q tip. I do not want to take her to the vet for something minor, so I was wondering if there was some natural oil that I can put on her ear for relief. Like me when I have itchy dry skin. If she does have ear mites or something buggy, can I put oil on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The itching could be caused by any number of things. You cat may also just have had an itchy ear and scratched it too hard, cutting herself a bit. People do this all the time too.

Inspect the ear daily. If after 3 days it is not healing or it looks redder or is oozing lymph/pus or bleeding or the crusty scab (clot) is getting bigger take your cat to the vet. Feel free to post some pictures and maybe some of us can make some better guesses as to what is wrong.

Often taking a pet the the vet for minor seeming illnesses is a "better safe than sorry" strategy. If your cat has ear mites they won't go away on their own and home remedies don't work well and may even hurt your cat.

Answer (score 3):

We have a cat with a similar condition, which turns out to be [allergic dermatitis](http://www.vet.cornell.edu/fhc/Health_Information/foodallergies.cfm). While it could be a different issue for your cat, food allergies often impact their skin and it can be relatively easy to find out if that's the case.

Some of the more common food allergens in cats includes chicken and grains, amongst others, common in many standard food choices. However, a number of companies make cat foods without those ingredients, including ones specifically designed to be hypoallergenic or with low ingredient volumes. We moved our cat onto a venison-based food without grains or chicken and since then, her scratching has gone way down and her ears are healing up and the fur filling back in.

You can consult with a vet on this, it's actually not that minor an issue, but if it is a food allergy, it's pretty easy to manage if you can use off-the-shelf food options with ingredients that they haven't been previously exposed to.

Answer (score 0):

Cats are very susceptible to skin problems, judging by the location of where your cat usually scratches, I would suggest you to look for black or yellow discharge, seems it might be a yeast infection. And don't worry too much(in case it is), it can be treated; an antifungal treatment might just do the trick. Just be sure to get your cat diagnosed before using any type of medicine on it.